# How can We Implement Depth First search for the n-nary tree?

Tags: c++, tree, tree-traversal

My goal is to insert new Node in n-nary tree By making it a child of Preferred Node. To do that I have to Implement find Operation for n-nary tree. Now I need to be able to do that using Both "Depth First search" and "Breadth First Search" **recursively**! 
  This Is My attempt And I Will be glad for any contribution. 
So Before Coming into the DFS  function I use a stack with root in it.

```
     struct TreeNode{
     TreeNode* firstChild;
     TreeNode* NextSibling;
     string element;
     }

     Stack.push(root);//before going into the DFS

void DFS(Node* n,string ParentStr, string NewStr){
     if(Stack.top()==NULL)
          return;

     TreeNode* node  = Stack.top();
     Stack.pop();
     if(node->element == ParentStr){
          insert new elemnt as its Child of node as base case;//Implemented()
          return;
      }
      if(node->nextSibling!=NULL){
         node = node->nextSibling;
         if(node->firstChild!=NULL)
              Stack.push(node);

        DFS(node,string ParentStr, string NewStr)
       }
     }
```